# jquery mobile: Is there a way to add a ticker in footer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making an mobile app and would like to add a ticker which will run non-clickable, static, pre-defined text or icons.

Can somebody give some pointers regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use: SLY: http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html

Centered horizontal style with long animation time might do the job. With setInterval that will trigger next item action you should be able to do the ticker.

Comment: Thanks...I'll check it out. Currently busy with something urgent.